# Variable incorrectly wrapped

Tags: bash, variables

I made a simple bash script to randomly change the DNS servers in my network settings. The script:

- checks how many DNS servers IP are available.
- chooses randomly 4 DNS servers IP
- puts these IPs into a string variable (each IP being separated by a ' ')
- removes the last character from the string variable (which is a ' '), and wraps it with double-quotes
- uses the string variable in an `nmcli` command

Here is the script:

```
servers=$(wc -l public-dns.txt)                                                                                                                                          
for i in `shuf -i 1-$servers -n 3`;do                                                                                                                                                                                     
   string+=$(sed -n "${i}p" public-dns.txt)                                                                                                                                                
   string+=" "
done
string="\""${string::-1}"\""    #also tried "\"""${string::-1}""\""                                                                                                                                                                  
echo $string   #only to check if the variable is correctly escaped and wraped
nmcli c mod tp ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes    
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

I run the script and get an error:

```
user@debian:~/dns$ bash test

"80.27.2.223 134.255.241.139 89.7.235.170"

Error: invalid or not allowed setting '134': '134' not among [connection, 802-11-wireless (wifi), 802-11-wireless-security (wifi-sec), 802-1x, ethtool, match, ipv4, ipv6, hostname, tc, proxy].
```

I thought the string var was not correctly escaped so I made this test:

```
nmcli c mod tp ipv4.dns "92.190.137.96 92.43.224.1 92.53.204.219" 
nmcli c mod tp ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

It works: As soon as I launch the connection, `/etc/resolved.conf` shows the new DNSs.
So obviously the issue comes from the way I escape and wrap the variable containing the IP addresses.

How should I wrap/escape my `$string` variable?

Comment: Just `string="${string::-1}"; echo "$string"` should work

Comment: Couldn't you just `nmcli c mod tp ipv4.dns "$(shuf -n 4 public-dns.txt)"`? Or if whitespace really has to be a space, then `… "$(… | tr '\n' ' ')"`.

Comment: @pmf: right in the middle. It must be my latin culture that makes me enjoying flourishes too much.

Answer (score 3):

As this is `bash`, you should be defining an *array* of DNS server addresses.

```
servers=$(wc -l public-dns.txt)                                                                                                                                          
for i in `shuf -i 1-$servers -n 3`;do   
   addresses+=( $(sed -n "${i}p" public-dns.txt) )                                                                                                                                                                                  
done
string="\""${string::-1}"\""    #also tried "\"""${string::-1}""\""                                                                                                                                                                  
echo "${addresses[*]}"

nmcli c mod tp ipv4.dns "${addresses[*]}" 
nmcli c mod tp ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

However, you don't need to repeated use `sed` to extract specific lines of the file. Just shuffle the whole thing and read the first `N` lines.

```
readarray -t addresses <( shuf -n3 public-dns.txt )
nmcli c mod tp ipv4.dns "${addresses[*]}" 
nmcli c mod tp ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: Note to readers: `"${addresses[*]}"` (in quotes) is the magic that joins the array elements into a space-separated string.